# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while finding class in package

Tags: java, spring, maven, teamcity, classloader

I have project (TeamCity plugin), written in Scala, packaged by maven and running on TeamCity(which uses Spring).

There is the dependency `com.ullink.slack.simpleslackapi` in my project. Now I try to update it (from 0.5.2 to 1.2.0) and become an error at runtime.

> Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.ullink.slack.simpleslackapi.impl.SlackWebSocketSessionImpl

The code that caused this exception is pretty simple:
`val session = SlackSessionFactory.createWebSocketSlackSession(config.oauthKey)`

My `build/pom.xml` file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>***</artifactId>
    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>build</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>***</groupId>
           <artifactId>***-server</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <finalName>***</finalName>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.parent.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                  <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                  <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>plugin-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                  </descriptors>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I've tried to append this dependency to this file and tried maven-shade-plugin — it does not help.

Could you advice what else can I try?

Comment: what do you mean, "the class became private package"?

Comment: @Stultuske oh I'm sorry, I've decided, that class access was changed, but it's not true. It always was without any access modifier.
https://github.com/Ullink/simple-slack-api/blob/master/sources/src/main/java/com/ullink/slack/simpleslackapi/impl/SlackWebSocketSessionImpl.java

Comment: This pom has a packaging type "pom" can you share the dependency's pom. It seems SlackWebSocketSessionImpl is not in your classpath at runtime

Comment: @Mumrah81 but before dependency update everything worked fine. Just added versions into question.

Comment: @alexkvak if you're not providing the pom using simpleslackapi how are we supposed to find what went wront with the dependency version change ? The pom shown to us is totaly irrelevant, at least show plugin-assembly.xml and the dependency's pom. What i've found is simpleslackapi team did change the scope of their dependencies from runtime to compile it may have a impact on your build...

Comment: I've just investigated and found that only update from 1.0.0 to 1.2.0 breaks runtime. So, is it possible, that dependency just built in wrong way?